# How can i get Date, Month and Year from a user input string eg 25/03/2012

Tags: java, string, date

Im struggling to break a String representing a date into the individual elements date, month,  year. As currently i have a user input the date as a string. `scan.nextLine()`

I would like to be able to break down the date into the individual elements because i want to assume the year is 2012 and i want them to just input date and month 23/03 as i dont want them inputting a different year.

Ive tried having a `String year = "2012";`  then adding `year` onto the user input string of date and month but my program still outputs whatever the user input for date and month and then 1970 :S

Comment: Is the format in consistent form? Is it in the same format as the date formatted?

Comment: Yes i have SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") which i want to change to dd/MM as i want to set the year to 2012 so i dont want them entering a year

Comment: Look at all the related posts on the right that ask how to convert a string to a date, and how to get elements from a date. And at least show your code if you want it fixed.

Comment: Thanks you i found my answer, when i was searching for similar i must not have been using the correct words as i didnt find those. will close this question

Comment: @NathanBarton the SimpleDateFormat approach will work.  You can parse the result into a Date value & extract the day, month value, or using a Calendar, you can set the year value directly

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the string, you could use the `SimpleDateFormat`, this would give you a Date value schaub you could then used to extract the values you want.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(value);
```